# VSCode throws errors for all mso properties...?

Tags: css, outlook, visual-studio-code

I'm writing an html email based on a template I didn't create. It has a lot of `mso` css tags like this: `mso-hide: all;`

I understand what these tags are for, but they make VSCode throw errors like this:

`[css.lint.unknownProperties] Unknown property: 'mso-table-rspace' [unknownProperties](252, 13)`

It's driving me up a wall. I tried installing some CSS extensions in hopes to eliminate the errors, but haven't found one that helps yet.

How can I make these `mso` properties go from Unknown to "known" in VSCode?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can customise the VSCode linting settings and ignore warnings on vendor prefixes, more information here:

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/css#_customizing-css-scss-and-less-settings

I haven't tried it myself, but it looks promising and an easy one to try before digging in any deeper.

Answer (score 4):

I was able to get rid of the warnings by using the link listed by Alex KeySmith, then went into VS Code settings and added items into the unknownProperties settings.

To do this (Mac) in VS Code app:

- I did a Command+Shift+P and typed settings
- Then, in the search settings box I typed unknownProperties
- I scrolled to the CSS > Lint: Valid Properties option in the search results
- and I added items to the CSS > Lint: Valid Properties list until my files showed no warnings.

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/adlNw.png) [VS Code unknownProperties items list]

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you. Specifically, I configured these under my Workspace settings so that they can be shared with other devs working on the same code.